# Debugging a hung process

Tags: java, debugging, strace

I'm trying to debug a hung java process. It is unresponsive to most of the JDK tools like jstats, jmap etc.

Here is the output of strace:

```
$ sudo strace -p <pid>
futex(0x7f14bb42a9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 6090, NULL <unfinished ...>
```

Output of wchan:

```
$ sudo cat /proc/<pid>/wchan          
futex_wait_queue_me%  

$sudo strace -f -p <pid>
Process <pid> attached with 15 threads - interrupt to quit
[pid  6105] futex(0x7f14b40cb954, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  6102] futex(0x7f14ba81e860, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  6101] futex(0x7f14b408aa54, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 43, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  6100] futex(0x7f14b4085f54, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 43, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid  6074] futex(0x7f14bb42a9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 6090, NULL
```

Other important information about the process:

- It runs under cgexec.

Need pointers on how to find the root cause of this process hang issue.

Comment: What does strace -f -p <PID> show ?

Comment: @exussum Updated question with output of strace -f -p <PID>

Answer (score 0):

One way is to take thread dump and analyze it for some deadlock, look for blocked threads and identify what resources they are blocked on.
If it is Oracle hotspot VM, then there are other few utilities you can run to check for deadlock detection.If the process is not responding, you can force the process to dump the stacktrace(thread dump) .
Read more about Oracel JVM troubleshooting. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/hangloop.html

Comment: As mentioned in the question, thread dump using jstack fails.Also,  I don't  want to kill the process as this hang is not easy to repro

Comment: Can you try , kill -3 pid, it WONT kill the process. If your process is running in a wrapper like tanuki, it will redirect the thread dump to wrapper log, rather than console. if your server machine  is configured to redirect the stdout to dev/null you wont see the output either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in android, so I have used the strace logs to check where its stuck. But strace you have to use in live mode.

I mean you have to keep running your program with strace.

I was using the below command to get the live strace logs.

```
strace -f -p $(pidof <process_name>)
```